# VirtualProtect failed to revert protections on mrdata section of ntdll, why?

Tags: windows, assembly, memory, dll, protection

i perform a loop in assembly where i am parsing the sections of ntdll change their memory permissions with **VirtualProtect** and then revert them back to their original permissions. the code looks like this:

```
lea eax, [OldProtect]
push eax                      //here it will store the old protection value
push PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
push dwSize                   //size of section
push lpAddress                //start address of section
call Virtual_Alloc
...
blahblah
...
lea eax, [OldProtect]
push eax
push OldProtect               //the protection value to revert
push dwSize                   //size of section               
push lpAddress                //address of section             
call Virtual_Protect
```

The loop runs correctly on the first three sections **.text**, **.RT** and **.data** which have initial memory permissions **ER**, **ER**, **RW** respectively.

The problem is that the in the next section which is the **.mrdata** section and it is readable only, the memory protection changed succesfully from **R** to **ERW**. But When i try to revert back to the old protection the return value is 0x00000050 in eax and i get an exception.

What i want to ask is  why? Is this a false use of VirtualProtect? Or has something to do with the .mrdata section

Comment: a non zero return value from VirtualProtect would indicate success according to the microsoft docs.
maybe we need more info about the exception and some reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

Oook i think i i found an answer but i didn't try it and needs more research, it seems there is a special Windows API function used to change protections on .mrdata called `LdrProtectMrdata( bProtect )`

source: http://mohamoha.club/2017/12/23/Bypass_CFG_Through_MRDATA/